# Measure an engine valve lift in a fixture

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, potentiometer, atmel

I work in a company which manufactures engine valves and we have a rig in which valves can be tested for endurance. The fixture in the rig is custom designed for the valve and the corresponding camshaft's lobe is fixed onto the top to actuate the valve. So I am looking for a setup to figure out valve lift (vs crank angle or cam angle) and currently I have an Arduino MEGA 2560 with me. I would like to know what kind of displacement sensor (with precision of 0.1mm) and encoder should I use, will an Arduino MEGA wil be fast enough? The maximum speed at which the camshaft rotates would be around 3000RPM.

[image: This is a picture of valve lift diagram]

This picture has 2 valves but in my case, I would have just one valve and I would have to calculate crank angle from cam angle (sort of).

Any ideas on this would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this testing being done on an actual running engine or some setup that is driven by some other means (perhaps an electric motor)?  A photo would help :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its not in an engine and its a rig setup where camshaft rotates with help of an electric motor.  I do not have a picture with me but i will definitely add one tomorrow as soon as I get to the lab.

Comment: OK, so can we also assume that there are no gas pressure or high temperatures to worry about?  That the whole assembly is running safely in free air?

Comment: LVDT with 3 coils around valve shaft I expect will give the accuracy you need. 1 Primary middle and 2 differential at ends driven at 100kHz or so if there is a ridge in diameter

Comment: @Wossname yes. No high temperature or gas involved. Just some oil for lubrication.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 thank you. I will check it out.

Answer (score 2):

"Non-contact linear proximity sensors" are a special breed.
Digital is easy, Linear is not.

These include; laser proximity sensors, inductive , capacitive.
Linearity and resolution and range are critical  limitations. Inductive are most common while laser are most accurate. Most proximity sensors are "digital" output for some threshold, so ignore those.

LVDS are linear by using a differential coil around a moving magnetic material to create a differential voltage,but smooth shafts *cannot* be detected and need a change in magnetic coupling by a small change in diameter equal to desired resolution.
 **This may not be practical.**

[Cap Sensor from 6:10mm range. (min:max), 35Hz max](http://www.ia.omron.com/products/family/474/)
**This does not have enough bandwidth for 3000 RPM = 50 Hz**

[image]

e.g. http://www.ia.omron.com/products/family/1457/application.html

[image]

Optical reflector is non-linear but can be made linear for a small range.
After detailed review of specs. I would then choose the Laser reflectometer for displacement with <0.01mm resolution.

This is where it becomes a shopping question. Good luck.,

Comment: So I have been looking for cheap sensors after reading your post and I found this Panasonic pna4602m IR sensor. Would this be fast enough for my application? This sensor is tuned for 38kHz.

Comment: Can you live with 1kHz BW?